# Getting "Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable'" using docker (inside vagrant on OS X)

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, docker, vagrant, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker-compose/docker inside a vagrant machine hosted on OS X. Running 'docker-compose up' always fails with

> mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

I can manually create the file just fine, however. (Using `touch` and `sudo -g vagrant touch`)

Does anyone know where to look to debug this?

---

Log:

```
db_1  | Initializing database
db_1  | mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
db_1  | 2016-05-21T22:55:38.877522Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
db_1  | 2016-05-21T22:55:38.877799Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2' services:   db:
    privileged: true
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

My Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  # config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL

  #####################################################################
  # Custom Configuration

  config.vm.define "dev" do |dev|

    # if File.directory?("~/Dev")
    #   dev.vm.synced_folder "~/Dev", "/vagrant/Dev"
    # end
    # custom: above does not work for symlinks
    dev.vm.synced_folder "~/Dev", "/home/vagrant/Dev"
#    dev.vm.synced_folder "~/Dev/docker", "/docker"

    dev.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.gui = false
      vb.memory = "2048"
    end

    dev.vm.provision "shell",
                        run: "always",
                        inline: <<-SHELL
      pushd /vagrant/conf
      chmod 755 setup.sh && ./setup.sh
      popd
    SHELL

    dev.ssh.forward_x11 = true

    # Install the caching plugin if you want to take advantage of the cache
    # $ vagrant plugin install vagrant-cachier
    if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
      # Configure cached packages to be shared between instances of the same base box.
      # More info on http://fgrehm.viewdocs.io/vagrant-cachier/usage
      config.cache.scope = :machine
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I'm not using vagrant, but I get exactly the same issue on my mac. Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: by the way - I removed the volumes section and it works (for my purposes). I assume you got that yml from https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/ ?

Comment: I'd do `chmod 777 ./data`, then start container, adjust owner and group of `./data` folder (`chown`, `chgrp`, `chmod`) and restart container to make sure everything still works)

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm your docker version?

I was getting the same error, but after I updated to the latest version it started to work.

I am now running:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.0-rc2, build 906eacd, experimental

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.8.0-rc1, build 9bf6bc6
```

Hope this helps with your problem.

Comment: how is this an answer?)